# How can I email a photo from Google plus via gmail?

Tags: gmail, google, google-plus

I have a photo under Photos on G+. I want to email it to someone. Ideally, I could do this from Gmail, but if I can do it from G+ that would be great.

I don't see any way of doing this from Gmail. In G+, I can select the photo, click on Share and put in an email address. But this generates a post on my feed (that I don't want), and only sends a tiny thumbnail to the person with a link to the G+ article. And it's not from my Gmail address.

Basically, I just want to compose a message in Gmail, and have the option to attach a photo that exists under my G+ photos. Why is this so hard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built in Share functionality is meant to just show a thumbnail, but there is a workaround for a purely Gmail solution.

In the compose window you should be able to attach an image. IN the "Add an Image" window click on "Web address (URL)"

Then, in your G+ window, right-click on the image you want to share and select "Copy image URL" You can now paste this URL into the "Add an Image" window and have it display in preview.

Comment: In my Compose window, all I see is a 'Attach a file', or Insert: Invitation. Clicking on 'Attach a file' shows my OS file chooser dialog. I don't see any place where I can specify a URL. Is this a feature that maybe my browser doesn't support? I'm using Firefox 10 on Scientific Linux 6.3.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the new Gmail compose window for reference. In your window/browser, do you see an image icon in the editor toolbar? Should look like a gray square with (lighter) gray mountains in the foreground. This is where to find the URL field.

Comment: There is nothing like that. I switched to the new Compose Window, and now I see what you're talking about. Google should make this easier still to do, but at least I know of a way to do it.